# Express is not saving updated row to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, updates

I have a function in Express and NodeJS where I can switch a Boolean value of an Item. So when the function is called the Boolean will be swapped to the other value. I do a console.log of Boolean. The object inside my MongoDB doesn't get updated. I have a Post, Get and GetAll request of the same objects to and from the MongoDB and they all work. So there is no problem with the connection to the database.

```
router.post("/payed/:id", (req, res) => {
  Item.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, item) => {
    item.childeren.forEach((child) => {
      if (child.name === req.body.name) {
        console.log(child.payed);
        child.payed = !child.payed;
        console.log(child.payed);
      }
    });
    item.save((saveErr, saveItem) => {
      if (saveErr) res.send(saveErr);
      return res.status(200).send(saveItem);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not an expert on MongoDB, but maybe you need to save the child node after you have modified it? Your code saves the parent but not the child and I doubt that there is an implicit save of children when you save the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.save()` in mongoose is used to save a new document. You can use `findOneAndUpdate` to update the record after fetching it. Try something like this:

```
router.post("/payed/:id", (req, res) => {
  Item.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, item) => {

    /* get children */
    let children = item.children;

    /* updating children's array */
    children.forEach((child) => {
      if (child.name === req.body.name) {
        child.payed = !child.payed;
      }
    });

    /* resaving the document */
    Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, 
        {children: children }, 
        {new: true}, 
        (saveErr, updatedDoc) => { 
            if (saveErr) res.send(saveErr);
              return res.status(200).send(updatedDoc);
         });
  });
});
```